# Passing Parameters to a Batch File from Javascript Inside Hyperion Interactive Reporting Studio

Tags: javascript, batch-file, hyperion

Inside of Hyperion Reporting Studio I have a document level script where I wish to call a batch file and pass arguments to the batch file.

Here is the code I have:

```
var Path = "W:\\directory\\Reference_Files\\scripts\\vbs\\SendEmail.bat"
var Email = "my.email@xxx.com"
var Subject = "My Subject"
var Body = "My Body"
var Attach = "W:\Maughan.xls"

Application.Shell(Path + " " + Email + " " + Subject + " " + Body + " " + Attach)
```

This code does not open the file, but gives the error message `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

If I pass `Path` by itself my bat file runs (giving me a warning because no parameters are passed) and I when I run the same code from the Shell Command, it works flawlessly.

Can anyone provide any insight into the correct syntax to pass into the `Application.Shell` method so that it reads my parameters and passes them to the batch file? I have been searching high and low online to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `var Attach = "W:\Maughan.xls"` should be `var Attach = "W:\\Maughan.xls"`.

Within a string the escape character `\` just escapes the next character so `Attach` will contain just `W:Maughan.xls`. To add `\` you need to use `\` twice.

**Update:**

It may have no difference in this particular case, because `W:Maughan.xls` means to look for `Maughan.xls` in the current directory on the drive `W` which is most likely `\`.

But what is definitely important are quotes around the parameters Subject and Body. In you code the constructed command is

```
W:\directory\Reference_Files\scripts\vbs\SendEmail.bat my.email@xxx.com My Subject My Body W:Maughan.xls
```

I sure that the bat file cannot distinguish between the subject and body (unless it expect exactly two words in each of them) so the right command most likely is

```
W:\directory\Reference_Files\scripts\vbs\SendEmail.bat my.email@xxx.com "My Subject" "My Body" W:\Maughan.xls
```

and you can check it by running the command above in `cmd`.

To construct it the parameters should be modified as follows:

```
var Path = "W:\\directory\\Reference_Files\\scripts\\vbs\\SendEmail.bat"
var Email = "my.email@xxx.com"
var Subject = "\"My Subject\""
var Body = "\"My Body\""
var Attach = "W:\\Maughan.xls"
```

(this correction was inspired by impinball's answer)

Comment: thanks for your response, but it didn't solve the issue. Also, since that is a parameter for the `.bat` file and not a file name, I don't think it needs the escape \

Comment: This updated answer got me where I need to be. Although, to note, I had to add the escape \ to the `var Path` as well, like in @impinball answer below.

Comment: Just a reminder, if not everyone has the same drive letter mapped, you might want to opt to use the UNC pathname.  Also, get in the habit of putting your pathnames in quotes, otherwise you might run into problems with spaces, and because some things may still expect you to use 8.3 short names if you don't have quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting an escaped quote on either side of the variable values. Depending on where the directory is, that may make a difference. The outside quotes in strings aren't included in the string values in JavaScript. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
var Path = "\"W:\\directory\\Reference_Files\\scripts\\vbs\\SendEmail.bat\""
```

instead of

```
var Path = "W:\\directory\\Reference_Files\\scripts\\vbs\\SendEmail.bat"
```

Comment: +1 for getting me in the right direction, though it didn't solve it completely.

Comment: I knew that between the two answers (given that I wasn't sure if I could edit it or not given my reputation at the time), it would come out.